# fog effect with volume

Tags: modeling, node-editor

BLEND FILE(https://pasteall.org/blend/8b5bf87ee219432b9af5482f055a3131)

I watched this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8U7HM6oB2zc), and it looks simple, but like anything else nothing is simple, and I run into another issue.
This is a screenshot from his video. As you can see my screenshot below, his is the same, yet my cube won't change from black and fill the volume with a fog effect. As proof the render viewport is selected, I shifted the black box over.

YouTube screenshot
[image]

My screenshot
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The reason it isn't working is because you connected your Volume Scatter to the _Surface_ input of the Material Output Node, instead of the _Volume_ input.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett sorry I forgot to change it back to volume. I tried surface to see if anything would change and meant to switch it back for the screenshot. I uploaded a new screenshot, showing you can't tell anything changed, so I still don't know why its all black

Comment: That is strange. Try turning off the transparent setting in film.

Comment: @TheLabCat I just uploaded a new image. It didn't change when I removed the transparent setting sadly

Comment: Are the normals inverted by any chance?

Comment: No, everything is blue. I'll remove all the extra stuff in the blend file and upload a link to it, so maybe you can see what is happening on your end

Comment: I downloaded your file and, after adding a light to the scene, the object appears as a pink, smoky cube, as it should. This makes me think it might be GPU related - try updating your graphics drivers.

Comment: I had a HDRI. Is that not enough, or is an actual light source required to make the fog effect to show. I am sadly working off a Mac laptop, so I don't think it has a GPU, but I don't know much about hardware products.

Comment: I agree with Christopher, it works fine here, it seems like it's a problem with the graphic card

Comment: also make sure you use the latest version of blender